# Access object literal with typed variable in TypeScript does not work

Tags: typescript

I'm translating Java code into TypeScript and I've come across something I can't understand.
I've create here object literal name `a` and I manage to use it as associative array.
Then I've define class `Node` and create variable name `n`, when I try to use the variable n as key to the associative array the tsc compiler fail with `Illegal property access`.
If I convert n variable to kk variable of type any everything works.

Why is that?

```
var a = {}
a['a'] = 3
a[4] = 5

class Node {

}
var n:Node = new Node();
a[n] = 44;  <---- Illegal property access

var kk: any = n;
a[kk] = 55
```

Answer (score 2):

In this statement:

```
a[n] = 44;
```

`a` is an object.

`n` is an instance of the Node class.

So you are trying to use a class as the key to a property on the `a` object.

When you use `kk`, which is an `any` type, TypeScript will assume that you know what you are doing and will assume that it will be a string or number at runtime. This is really ignoring the problem.

You could use the type of the `n` variable, which is a string:

```
a[typeof n]
```

Comment: I see. using typeof is not the answer. I have getId function on the Node class so I'll use n.getId(). I guess I just forgot it is javascript after all so there are no real associative array.